# Converting a byte* to a string, using PubSubClient on ESP8266

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, mqtt

Hello kind people of Stackoverflow.

I'm using the PubSubClient library to publish and receive messages on MQTT. But i'm battling with receiving data in the right "format".

The callback function from this library, uses a *byte to handle payloads coming from MQTT, but i need to convert this *byte to a string.

I'm expecting to receive a payload of "dragon" and "boa", so i need to react upon the different strings.

See below code for reference.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction :-)

```
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print((char)payload);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
    
  }
  Serial.println();

    if (payload = "dragon"){
    Serial.println("dragon");
  }
  else if (payload = "boa"){
    Serial.println("boa");
  }

  // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
    // but actually the LED is on; this is because
    // it is active low on the ESP-01) 
    }
   else {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't only cast `payload` to `char*`. `payload` is an array of received bytes and `length` is the size of received data in that array. If the bytes are characters and you would know that there is one more position allocated in that array, you could put a 0 to `payload[length]` and by cast to `char*` it would become a *zero terminated string*. But you can't know if there is that one more byte allocated, so you must copy the payload to your buffer of chars and set a zero at the end.

You can use `strcmp` C function to compare strings or you can use [memcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) to compare `payload` with a string.